# How do I copy an entire directory into dist/ using custom webpack with angular-builders?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-builder

I'm using Angular builders to add some additional files and folders in the `dist/` directory generated. In this case I want to have the directories `src/assert/puppies` and `src/assert/kittens` copied into a folder called `animals/`.

In other words, I want this

```
src/
 |--- assets/
        |----puppies/
                |--- *.jpg
                |--- ....
        |----kittens/
                |--- *.jpg
                |--- ....
```

to become this

```
dist/
 | main.js
 | vendor.js
 | ...
 |--- animals/
         |--- images...
```

---

**angular.json**

This is the relevant portion of my angular.json file:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json",
              {
                "input": "node_modules/jquery/dist",
                "glob": "jquery.js",
                "output": "./vendor"
              }
            ],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
            }
          },
```

This is my `custom-webpack.config.js`. I already have this content in there because I want these scripts to be compiled and copied over.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "special-scripts/login":
      "src/custom/login/login.ts",
    "special-scripts/logout":
      "src/custom/logout/logout.ts"
  }
};
```

**What do I add to `custom-webpack.config.js` to get it to copy over those asset folders into `dist/` in the way I described above?**

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/).

Import it into your custom-webpack.config.js:

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
```

Then add it to your plugins:

```
plugins: [
  new CopyPlugin([
    { from: './src/assets/*', to: 'dist/animals/' },
  ]),
  ...
]
```

Comment: Yes but how exactly? The examples they give don't work in this situation

Comment: Is the plugin throwing an error, or just not doing anything?

Comment: Where am I supposed to put this `plugins` property ? Where does it fit in to my `custom-webpack.config.js`?

Comment: 'plugins' should be a property of module.exports. The require should go at the top of the file.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I do not even get a directory `animals` in `dist`

Comment: I'd try adding the [progress-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/progress-plugin/) to the plugins in your webpack config, and checking in the terminal to see whether CopyPlugin is logging at all. If it's firing but not having an effect, that would suggest it's a path/context issue or similar, as it won't even create the directory if it can't locate any files to copy.